# NullReferenceException in Page_Load

Tags: asp.net

I have developed my project in asp.net 3.5. It works fine in localhost, when i published in the web sometimes its working fine but sometimes i am getting the following error. I think some error while conecting to the server but dont know exactly. Please help me to do it fine.

Server Error in '/' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.] Result.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +128 System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14 System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35 System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99 System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627

Comment: do you have code that executes on the Page_Load event?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Enable debugging in your web.config file (Debug="True") and turn RemoteErrors="On".  This will provide a much more detailed error message so that you can find what is throwing the NullReferenceException.  Once solved, remember to reset these configurations.

Comment: That will give him the line number, but he's still going to have to learn to read a stack trace. He doesn't even seem to know it's his own Page_Load method that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code inside your Page_Load method, its throwing a null refernce exception

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Request pipeline is giving the issue here not the page.
you need to check and trace HTTPContext here